# Did Michael Sheen (Aziraphale) use a body double in this Good Omens scene?

Tags: tv, good-omens

In the recently released TV miniseries ["Good Omens"](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1869454/) based on the book by Pratchett and Gaiman, there is a wonderful character exposition scene where

> Sheen's Aziraphale character dances the gavotte. (It's part of a side bit on the age-old question of how many angels can dance on the head of a pin.) 
>  I've watched the short clip a few times and the character's face is never in focus while his feet are visible.

Was there a stunt double for this scene? I can't find their name credited anywhere.

In the alternate version of the scene posted below in a comment, there are no feet visible at all...

(Edited to add): part of the motivation for this question was the bonus cast interview section on the Seven Brides for Seven Brothers DVD, where they talked about how the budget didn't cover seven dancers for the main cast, which was hidden in the big dance numbers by careful editing so the non-dancers' feet were never in view of the camera.

Comment: not sure why the downvote - it's a good question, the dance shown is well executed, and it would be fun to know if Sheen is even more talented than widely known (unless it's extremely common knowledge that he's a dancer as well?). No need for the spoiler tag though imo, but I don't care enough to edit it out

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neil Gaiman just posted [an alternate take of the Gavotte dance scene](https://neil-gaiman.tumblr.com/post/185589892546/okay-just-this-once-take-2-of-the-gavotte-we), and Sheen is both clearly visible, and clearly dancing.

The focus issues are most likely intended to show that the filmic image is quite poor, especially since, as Neil puts it, "somebody has invented a moving picture camera rather ahead of schedule"

This evidence suggests that it is indeed Sheen Gavotting away on his own.

Comment: That was cool, thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.studiodaily.com/2019/06/good-omens-dp-gavin-finney-earthly-otherwordly-camera-delights/ about the cinematography:

> We laughed during every single take of that scene because what Michael Sheen was doing with the dance was so glorious.